# Solr how to exclude custom fields from my schema

Tags: solr

My problem is simple. I have about 30 fields in my index. For several cases I want to exclude two fields from schema. It won't be happening always. Only sometimes based on customer data.

For example if I search for "test".

I was trying to add something like this to my $querySolr:

```
squerySolr->addParam('fq','available:(1) AND (!field1 = '*test*' AND !field2 = '*test*');
```

Problem is when other active fields will match phrase '*test*' - there be no result. How to simple exclude field1 AND field2 from searching ?

Comment: Is it the case that always you want to store **field1** and **field2** but never query on them?

Answer (score 0):

For excluding from query, you can simply add `-(field1:"*test*" AND field2:"*test*")`.

But if you never want to query on **field1** and **field2**, then simply modify in schema. Make `indexed="false"` for those fields.